# Trying to set the values to the model in initialize function of backbone, but not working

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

```
initialize: function(options){
        var that= this;
        that.options = options ;
        that.options.model.fetch({

                success     : function(model, response){
                    that.options.model.set({
                        data1 : response,
                        data2  : [{
                                                attributes : {
                                                    data3 : response
                                                    }
                                             }]

                    });

                },error     : function(model, response){
                    console.log("error");
                }
       });
```

Only data1 is getiing set with response value but data3 is not getting set, it is showing as the default value which is set in the model.

Comment: Where is the above initialize method located. Is it inside a Backbone View. Can you also post that piece of code where  you trying to access data3 attribute

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are setting the data not inside `initialize`, but inside `success` callback (which is asynchronous) of `fetch` method so you should access these new data only after `success` called.

And one thing I noticed you are using the same model to fetch data and set data. Actually `fetch` should populate model with data automatically with JSON response. But in your case you may override it in `success` method.